# Pywinauto shifting to select folder box

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm new to python. I was trying to automate a java app using Pywinauto.
 Initially every thing setting correct until I came across select folder. Im unable to focus on that window and type the path below.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application,findwindows
from  pywinauto import mouse
import time
app = Application(backend='uia').start('java -jar ../../imp/VIMS/VIMSDownloadFiles_v2.jar',wait_for_idle=False)
time.sleep(5)

appd = Application(backend='uia').connect(title='Download VIMS Files')
z = app.DownloadVIMSFiles.child_window(title="Select the File Types from the given checkbox :\nIf any of the File types are not available,\nPlease enter in text field with comma( , ) separated if there are more than one : ", auto_id="JavaFX19", control_type="Text").wrapper_object()
z.type_keys('CL3, CL_, DL3, TR3, TR_, HS3, HS_, EC3, EC_, DL_, DL_CNF, ER3, CU_, CU3')
a = app.DownloadVIMSFiles.child_window(title="Select Folder", auto_id="JavaFX68", control_type="Button").wrapper_object().click()
a.click_input()
selectWIn.child_window(title="Select Folder", auto_id="1", control_type="Button").click_input()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3K7R.png)

Answer (score 0):

the **Select Folder** is a new window, so it is not a children window from *selectWIn*. You need to relocate the window. The following code could be used for locating the **Select Folder** window.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app=Application().connect(title_re="Select Folder")
select_folder_window=app['Select Folder']
select_folder_window.draw_outline()
```

Now u could see the green block around the window.